# How do you iterate through an array of strings while changing each string in the array using a given set of instructions?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Given an array of strings, I want to change every string into a string that is composed of the original letters from the original string sorted alphabetically.

So, given an array:

```
words = ["apple", "orange"]
```

the method should return:

```
["aelpp", "aegnor"]
```

---

While using:

```
words[0].chars.sort(&:casecmp).join
```

returns the desired string in the array, so I have tried to use:

```
words.each {|y| y.chars.sort(&:casecmp).join }
```

but this returns the array in its original state.

I am learning Ruby as we speak and do not understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use the following:

```
words.map {|y| y.chars.sort(&:casecmp).join }
```

Because I wanted to transform my original array into another array.

Comment: Consider marking your own comment as the answer.

Comment: @SunnyJuneja I certainly will, just have to wait out the timer.  Btw, ty for the formatting changes.